# API, сохранение очков, как защитить от накрутки

Tags: api, rest

Добырй день,

Задача такая - есть сайт для изучения языков, на нем есть разные типы уроков - учить слова, грамматические упражения, игры. За прохождение каждого урока начисляются очки.

Отправляется запрос на АПИ с данными: user_id, points, type, lesson_id (type - тип урока), очки сохраняются в базу.

Сейчас есть такая проблема, что по идее я могу открыть нетворк, скопировать оттуда запрос к апи и 100 раз его запустить и накрутить себе очки

Какой лучший способ сделать защиту от накрутки?

Answer (score 0):

На каджый урок выдаешь одноразовый токен и отправляешь его с результатом урока. Токееном может быть например хеш от пользователя и номера урока. Так за каждый урок можно будет получить только одну оценку.